# Firebase Remote Config Condition based on event sent

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

Helllo. I'm following some firebase tutorials regarding the use of remote config and contitions to achieve a A/B test framework (for instance, this one https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/config-analytics) but the examples only uses the `User in random percentile` rule, and I want to know if I can combine the `User in random percentile` with some event triggered, or in other words: I want to create my segments only in users that triggered some event in the past (users that viewed some content, for instance) withtout using the user properties. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. A/B testing is to check if user behavior changes with a new tweak or iteration.
You could , hard-code different activities when that event is triggered, if you so wish. Or if the firebase team decides to add that option in future.
I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to kinda get at what you're looking for:

1. Create an Audience in Firebase Analytics based on people who have triggered some event. Then you can combine this Audience with a random percentile to get at the A/B test you're looking for. Keep in mind, however, that audiences have a few restrictions: a) They're not retroactive, so you won't be able to get people who have triggered this event in the past, and b) Once a user joins an audience, they don't leave it.
2. Set a User Property when this event is triggered, then combine this audience with a random percentile to get at the A/B test you're looking for. I know you said in your original question that you don't want to use a User Property for this, but it's probably the most straighforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an 'Activation Event' if that's what you're looking for...

From https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/abtest-config:

> (optional) To set an activation event to ensure that only users who have first triggered some Analytics event are counted in your experiment, click Advanced options, and then choose an Analytics conversion event or another Analytics event.